# Cannot find Overloaded operator<<

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a draw function that returns vector<  >.

```
vector< vector<char> > draw(char penChar, char fillChar) const{
        const int breadth = this->height;
        const int length = this->width;
        vector< vector<char> > temp(breadth, vector<char>(length));
        for (int x = 0; x <= height - 1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= width - 1; y++) {
                temp[0].push_back(penChar);
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

I overloaded the operator<< like this

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  const vector< vector<char> >& grid) {
        for (const vector<char>& vec : grid) {
            for (const char& ch : vec) {
                os << ch;
            }
            os << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    }
```

But when I run `cout << rect.draw('2', 'w') << endl;` I get the following error.

```
entererror: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<char> >’)
cout << rect.draw('2', 'w') << endl;
```

Can someone tell why the compiler cannot find this method?
Also I have another operator<

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Shape& obj) {
        //Some code
  return os;
    }
```

But this seems to work fine.

Comment: Why is the first one a `friend`?

Comment: @LogicStuff because it's declared within a class declaration scope (that we have inconveniently not been provided with).

Comment: Is there a problem if I make it friend?

Comment: So, it's better if I write this outside the class scope? But even then how is the 2nd one working fine?

Comment: @KAY_YAK what exactly are you friending that operator *to* ? Normally you friend an operator because the operator is looking to access private members of an object instance *of the class your friending from*. But you're not doing that. A free-operator-function should be sufficient here. In short, your operator has nothing to do with whatever class that decl is within. That it is designed to output something returned my some member of that class is irrelevant.

Comment: Oooh!! Yes, that function doesn't need to be a friend at all!! Thanks :)

Comment: @KAY_YAK Rossi's answer says as-much, and deserves a worthy selection.

Comment: But tell me, would it be wrong if I made that a friend? I mean I don't get how the compiler is working here? When I do it as a friend it still should have worked right irrespective of whether I access private members within or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply put the function `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  const vector< vector<char> >& grid)` outside the class and without friend, like this:

```
class Foo
{
  //draw function and other stuff
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  const vector< vector<char> >& grid)
{
}
```

Since in the function you defined there is no variable of (in this example) Foo class the ADL (Argument-dependent lookup) cannot be used so if you defined the function inside the class compiler cannot find it.

Comment: You should explain why this makes a difference (assuming it does)

Comment: I get it that since it doesn't access any private members I shouldn't make it friend. But, why it won't work if I made it friend?